# Dynamic Brushes - GLPaint

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, paint, brush

I was wondering it there are any example codes to have dynamic brushes in GLPaint.
I'm searching for something that is similar to photoshop where for example the brush pattern gets resized and rotated randomly to have a more realistic texture when you're drawing.

I've added an example below to show the difference without dynamics and with dynamics.
Is it difficult to create something like this using GLPaint as a base?

http://users.telenet.be/afshar/Untitled-4.jpg

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK in GLPaint the brush is applied by a simple textured quad. So yes it is possible by applying the right transformations on the quad.